# Changing protocol from net.tcp to http, Wcf, gives me the error "No corresponding start element is open"

Tags: wcf, configuration

I am required to update the endpoints from **net.tcp** to **http** and all of them work fine except for one.

Configuration on the client web config side is as follow.

```
 <endpoint address="http://myseriesservices/Quote.svc" behaviorConfiguration="DynamicTransportBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpConfiguration" contract="EbqQuoteServiceReference.IQuote" name="Quote" />
  <!--<endpoint address="net.tcp://myseriesservices/Quote.svc" behaviorConfiguration="DynamicTransportBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Quote" contract="EbqQuoteServiceReference.IQuote" name="Quote" />-->
```

and wsHttpBinding

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="httpConfiguration" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

and this is the configuration on the server side.

```
 <service behaviorConfiguration="MexBehavior" name="OM.Mec.BF.Ebq.Quote">
    <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Large" name="BasicHttpBinding_Large" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="OM.Mec.SC.Ebq.IQuote" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <!--<endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="NetTcp_StreamingResponse" name="Quote" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="OM.Mec.SC.Ebq.IQuote" />
    <endpoint address="Mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="QuoteService.MexBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://myseriesservices/Quote.svc" />
        <!--<add baseAddress="net.tcp://myseriesservices/Quote.svc" />-->
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

and **BasicHttpBinding_Large**

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Large" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"  allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
```

What could the reason be for getting this error?
I debugged on the backend and a call is made to the DB successfully but at the point of returning the data to the client it fails. net.tcp if fine, it only fails with http

Comment: What is the full stack trace? Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229336/error-no-corresponding-start-element-is-open-when-calling-a-webservice-wher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be one of these reasons for this error

1. I think your call is failing due to the size of the object which you return from your service.
2. A second reason could be the serialization settings of your service as Net TCP (BinarySerializer) and HTTP (DatacontractSerializer) bindings use different serialization by default.

Solution for big size response would break your response in chunks and send it over HTTP. You can refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/chunking-channel

Answer (score 1):

Which way did you use to host the service? If IIS is, we should not add the base address in the configuration since we should add the base address in the IIS site binding module.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HWUd.png]
Besides, it seems that the binding configuration is not coherent between the server and the client.
I suggest you call the service on the client side by using Adding service reference to generate the client proxy class, like below.
[image]
It could maintain the consistency of the binding configuration between the client and the server.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exist.